# Salesforce Insert/Update a QueryResult field?

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, salesforce

So we have a data structure 'Case' such as a return case, refund case, etc, etc. One of the fields is a 'CaseComments' field. This field is (in the C# wsdl generated code) a QueryResult Field.

I know that to query the CaseComments I can use a:

```
SELECT (SELECT ParentId, CommentBody FROM Case.CaseComments) FROM Case
```

to get all the case comments' ParentId and CommentBody fields. However it's the inserts that I'm not getting, or finding any reasonable documentation on how to do.

I would prefer to use a strongly typed query such as:

```
    Case updateCase = new Case();
    updateCase.Id = caseToAddToID;
    updateCase.CaseComments = new QueryResult();
    updateCase.CaseComments.records = (sObject[])new CaseComment[1];
    updateCase.CaseComments.records[0] = new CaseComment();
    ((CaseComment)updateCase.CaseComments.records[0]).ParentId = caseToAddToID;
    ((CaseComment)updateCase.CaseComments.records[0]).CommentBody = noteToAdd;

    binding.update(new sObject[]{updateCase});
```

but when doing something like this I get an error:

```
    Error: getting record type info.
    INVALID_FIELD: No such column 'CaseComments' on entity 'Case'. 
    If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append 
    the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL
    or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

But if I try using create() on just the caseComment data structure, it inserts without error, but doesn't get associated to the Case appropriately, and I can't seem to find them.

Comment: Okay, my mistake. Aparently I was providing a null ID field. I got it to work.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprised that worked for you, you may want to check that the new case comments are actually saving.  In APEX, you get an exception if you try and write to a child relationship field (i.e. `updateCase.CaseComents.records = (sObject[]) new CaseComment[1];`), although you are allowed to add records to the array even though they won't be updated.

For example, this throws an error

```
 Case updateCase = new Case();
 updateCase.caseComments = new List<CaseComment>(); // throws compile error in APEX
```

You can do this but it the new case comment won't be saved.

```
 Case updateCase = [select (select id from CaseComments) from Case where id = '1234'];
 updateCase.caseComments.add(new CaseComment(commentBody = 'comment));
 binding.update(new sObject[]{ updateCase });
```

The proper way would be to create them in a separate DML statement

```
 CaseComment newComment = new CaseComment();
 newComment.parentId = caseToAddToId;
 newComment.commentBody = noteToAdd;
 binding.update(new sObject[] { newComment });
```